# Why am I getting a typeError of property 'length' undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm getting "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" for:

```
    success: function(data) {
      for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          var callData = data.query.search[i].title;
          $("#results").html(JSON.stringify(callData)); 
      }
```

Since I'm passing `data` into the function, shouldn't `data.length` be recognized in the for loop? For context I'm making an AJAX call.

Comment: Try logging the `data` in the console, then you'll understand. It would be a JSON response.

Comment: Console.log(data) and see what are you getting.

Comment: It seems like even if you are passing in `data` correctly, you want `i < data.query.search.length` anyway...

Comment: `data` might be null, undefined, or contains the result in a structure not as expected. You need to troubleshoot it with `console.log(data)` or add a `debugger;` statement in the line before the loop so you can debug the runtime code in your browser console. - Or just read what is wrong in the above comment and don't learn to troubleshoot :)

Answer (score 1):

In most cases it means that `data` might be `null` or `undefined`.

But here you have different case: Your data is an object, not a collection, so it does not have length property.

You are iterating over `data.query.search` collection, but you are checking `data` length

```
success: function(data) {
   if(!data.query.search) { return; } // check if collection is present
   for(i = 0; i < data.query.search.length; i++) {
      var callData = data.query.search[i].title;
      $("#results").html(JSON.stringify(callData)); 
   }
 }
```